# Deserialize to object whose field should be deserialized based on runtime

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have  a class like below,

```
class KafkaJsonWrapper{

String version;
Object kafkaEvent;

}
```

when I serialize this object , I pass the kafkaEvent which is from different services and datamodel is different.

For instance,

```
KafkaJsonWrapper obj = ..
obj.setKafkaEvent(new AccountEvent()) 
obj.setKafkaEvent(new BonusTriggeredEvent()) //OR
etc..
objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(object)
```

However when i deserialize it how can i deserialize to type which i used for serialization.

```
    ACTUAL:
    KafkaJsonWrapper wrapper = objectMapper.readValue(buffer.array(), start, length, type); //type is KafkaJsonWrapper
    wrapper.getKafkaEvent()// inside this KafkaJsonWrapper is LinkedHashMap all the time.
    EXPECTED:
    KafkaJsonWrapper wrapper = objectMapper.readValue(buffer.array(), start, length, type); 
    wrapper.getKafkaEvent() // should be the type when it was serialzed like BonusTriggeredEvent etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subtypes

Example

```
   @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type") @JsonSubTypes({
         
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Square.class, name = "square"),
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "circle")
   })
   static class Shape {
      public String name;    
      Shape(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }
   }

   @JsonTypeName("square")
   static class Square extends Shape {
      public double length;
      Square(){
         this(null,0.0);
      }
      Square(String name, double length){
         super(name);
         this.length = length;
      }
   }

   @JsonTypeName("circle")
   static class Circle extends Shape {
     ...
```

The deserializer should only need the class type, not start/end positions